# El resultado de HOSTNAME pasarlo a una variable. BATCH

Tags: cmd, batch, .bat

Pues así, me gustaría que el resultado del comando HOSTNAME me lo guarde en una variable
he buscado por muchos lados sin tener resultados satisfactorios. cabe mencionar que se lo básico en programación batch.

otra cosa, la única solución que encontré (que no se hacer) es mandar el resultado de HOSTNAME a un archivo de texto y a su vez regresar lo a una variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este code se puede hacer una variable con el resultado del comando hostname

```
@echo off
hostname>host.output
set /p variable=<host.output
del host.output /F /S /Q
echo %variable%
```

El "<" indica que se debe extraer la primera línea del archivo definido después del símbolo, en este caso "host.output"

Comment: Creo que deberías especificar que tu solución necesita todos los permisos de escritura y lectura en el directorio, porque crea un archivo, escribe en él, lo lee para obtener el hostname y sucesivamente elimina el archivo. Sin alguno de estos permisos tu script fallará.

Comment: Es cierto, pero presuponiendo que lo ejecutará en algún sitio donde tenga permisos de lectura y escritura completos funcionará sin problemas.

Y para detectar esos permisos (por ejemplo con icacls) hay que usar aún más código que sería innecesario

Comment: En mi opinión, ya que existe la forma de hacerlo sin tener que disponer de permisos o crear un archivo, considero tu respuesta útil como una alternativa, pero no la mejor opción.

Comment: Se puede hacer de otra manera con for /f, pero el OP preguntó también por la forma en donde se importa desde un archivo, respondiendo sus dos preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

En Windows 10 lo ideal es usar `COMPUTERNAME` en lugar de `HOSTNAME`.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET host=%COMPUTERNAME%
ECHO %host%

PAUSE
```